# namespace, class name and event handler obfuscation

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I have a .NET application. When I obfuscated the assembly, namespace, class name and application event handlers ( like a button click event handler) does not get obfuscated. I have tried it with 2 different obfuscation productions but it seem like same behaviour. Is it normal to not obfuscated namespaces, class names and application event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, public/protected members are not obfuscated because there is chance that they may get referenced by external applications - it appears to be case here (*assuming that event handler is protected scope*). So generally, Obfuscator tool offers option to obfuscate them as well as - check the tool documentation - for example, Dotfuscator Community Edition 4.0 has [library mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227298%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that will not obfuscate public/protected members.